# Invalid CSRF Verification with Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a HTMl form i created and i am trying to get Django to process. Here is my main.html (shortened):

```
      <form action="/polls/thanks/" method="post" name = 'tag_name'>
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="w-3/4 py-10 px-8">
                <table class="table-auto">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="py-10 h-4">
                                <div class="mr-64">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-8 w-8">
                                    <label class="ml-4">test</label>

                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
```

and here is the views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render



def get_name(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = request.POST.get('tag_name')
        print(form)


        if form.is_valid():


            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/thanks/')




    return render(request, 'main.html', {'form': 'mainform'})

def thanks(request):
    form = request.POST.get('tag_name')
    print(form)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)

    return render(request, 'thanks.html')
```

Here is /mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),


]
```

and here is /mysite/polls/urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_name, name='index'),
    path('thanks/', views.thanks, name='thanks/'),

]
```

yet it still returns a Invalid CSRF Verification if I try and submit the form

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py` that is mapped to this?

Comment: The webpage loads so i doubt thats the issue, its just that when I submit instead it gives me a CSRF Error for the form. Ill attach it anyway

Comment: Is `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` included in your MIDDLEWARE? Can you share your `settings.MIDDLEWARE`

Comment: `MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]`

Comment: can you check in the browser's console's network tab to make sure the CSRF cookie is getting set correctly? If you are setting a secure cookie and your application is running on http, the backend will not receive the CSRF cookie